# Symfony2 images or extra folder issue

Tags: symfony, composer-php, assetic

I am using the symfony 2, composer and sass framework

I have extra folders called files/ and images/ under MYBundle/Resources/public/

some reason this files or images folder are not creating under web/ .. when I run the command:

> php app/console assets:install

However they do create under web/bundles/mybundle/files..

same as images folder : web/bundles/mybundle/images..

I only have these folders.. under web..

```
web/ 
  bundles/
  css/ 
  js/
```

how to get my two other folders under web/ which are images and files folders...

like this..

```
web/ 

 bundles/ 
 images/ 
 css/ 
 js/ 
 files/
```

because I need to keep some files like termsandconditions.pdf in the files/ folder..

### my configuration in config.yml is :

```
# Assetic Configuration

parameters:
    # Assetic
    assetic.filter.compass.images_dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/images
    assetic.filter.compass.http_path:  /images
    assetic.filter.compass.images_dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/files
    assetic.filter.compass.http_path:  /files

assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    filters:
        sass:    ~
        compass: ~
        cssrewrite: ~
```

---

path in twig file is:

```
<div class="small-4 columns">
                <p>I accept the <a href="{{ asset('/files/terms_and_conditions.pdf') }}" target="_blank"><span class="pinkText">Terms and Conditions</span></a></p>
            </div>
```

---

please let me know if anyone the steps... I am knew to Symfony

Answer (score 0):

Everything in your public folder is being copied to web folder when you install the assets.

So create a folder file and then call them like these:

```
<p>I accept the <a href="{{ asset('bundles/bundleName/files/terms_and_conditions.pdf') }}">
```

or use a controller to server it

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse;



Class Controller ....
    function downloadTermsAndCondsAction() {

    $file = __DIR__.'/../../../../web/bundles/bundleName/files/terms_and_conditions.pdf';
    $response = new BinaryFileResponse($file);
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Hi.. Thanks Albert.. but, i don't want to show the full path to my bundle to users on frontend.. so thats why if i can create my files folder under web/ then i don't need to use the full path to bundle right!

Comment: So create a route and in a controller you serve the file with a BinaryFileResponse

Comment: It is not a good idea to create a controller just to serve a static file if no logic is needed for that. It will consume CPU and memory for no added value, and should be avoided every time it is possible.

Comment: I agree @totphe this is why the controller is the second option I gave. It was an example on how to serve this file via a controller a You can add annotations to protect it by roles later on or just record which ip/user download it for later usage.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, I would suggest to put manually your terms_and_conditions.pdf inside the web/ folder. There is no need to use the bundle/app/assetic to solve that case, and certainly not using a controller for that.

Comment: Is this an answer to the question or just an oversized comment?

Comment: It is actually the right answer to the question. Sometimes people don't know that you should not use assets when it is not necessary. The web folder can and should perfectly hold static assets for a project. Bundles are made for reusability, not especially to hold all your project files.